# Сортировка по имени

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Имеется интернет магазин, где сортировка позиций товара возможна лишь перетаскиванием позиций. Это я так понимаю javascript. Вот такой код.

```
/* подключаем плагин sortable для итемов */
$("div.plug_cat_right_box ul").sortable
({
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        arr = new Array();

        $(this).children().each(function(){arr.push(this.id);});

        $.post("/plugins/catalog/back/settings/scr/setRange.scr.php", 
               {mas: arr,range:'items',}, 
               function(){});
```

Подскажите, как сделать сортировку по алфавиту?
Как лучше сортировать? Приоритет на русский алфавит по идее должен быть.

---

Небольшое дополнение к вопросу.

Пример названий:

> STU-40 Вешалка красная, Крючок 200мм,
>   ВЕНГЕ П-440/3 Витрина стеклянная,
>   В-850/4 Витрина стеклянная
>   А где то просто русские слова.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: т.е. вам понадобится Array.prototype.sort() и String.prototype.localeCompare()

Comment: Пожалуйста можно поподробнее как эти функции прописать...

Comment: подробнее по ссылке.

Comment: Хорошо в примерах указаны значения например a,b или 0,1,2,3,4. А мне то что писать?

Comment: @Grosso2020 свой код, [вот  сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_non-ASCII_characters) внимательно посмотрите.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение к вопросу. У меня названия идут например
STU-40 Вешалка красная,
Крючок 200мм,
ВЕНГЕ П-440/3 Витрина стеклянная,
В-850/4 Витрина стеклянная,
Как лучше сортировать? Приоритет русский алфавит по идее должен быть.

Comment: Зачем вам js для первичной сортировки. смотрите на стороне сервера где происходит выгрузка. скорее всего там уже есть сортировка по умолчанию и нужно всего лишь поменять параметр по которому сортировать

Comment: Сайт на php+mysql функциями php добиться сортировки не получилось Порядок (order by) идет по item_id который является name в таблице. Перебрал все функции от sort до....вообщем все. Ноль эмоций. И сортировка получается только вручную переносом как я описал выше. Думается что есть универсальное решение.